# Override Document_New() in Office 2010 from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm writing some VBA code (in Excel) to automatically produce reports at work. These reports need to have a specific format, which is easily available through our Company templates. It's all in MS Office 2010.

However, all of these templates have `Document_New()` subs, which sparks some VBA-code that I don't want initiated, and sadly don't have direct access to (company rules, hell yeah!).

Is there a way to override the `Document_New()` macro? Right now, my VBA code for opening a document, which sparks the `Document_New()` macro, is as follows:

```
Sub GenerateReport()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    WordApp.Documents.Add Template:="Letter.dot"        ' the "error" is produced at this lie

    Dim SaveStr As String
    SaveStr = "KommRapp-" & Date & ".docx"
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveStr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like:

```
Sub OpenWordDocAndBlockMacros()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'Just to see whats happening
    WordApp.Visible = True

    Dim InitialSecurityAutoSetting As MsoAutomationSecurity
    'Save Automations Security Setting
    SecurityAutoSetting = WordApp.Application.AutomationSecurity
    WordApp.Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=" Place Template file path here"


    'Do some stuff with the template


End Sub
```

I have tested it, using Excel VBA to open a Word.dotm which has a `Sub` called `Document_New` in the `ThisDocument` module and it worked.

Comment: I get error on line `WordApp.EnableEvents = False`, that says the object doesn't support this property or method...

Comment: Yes! This fixed it. Thanks!